# Monitor/Watch a folder in R

Tags: r, rstudio

I have to develop an algorithm that monitors a folder. As soon as a file is dropped in this folder my algorithm will process that. My problem is that I could not find any function that will keep running and watching a folder.

Does anyone know any library for this or if I can do it with RStudio Connect?

Comment: Do you have to use pure R here?  Something like Java would be much better suited for this task.  I think R has the ability to call Java, so this could be an option for you.

Comment: maybe servr can help you: https://github.com/yihui/servr

Comment: Java is a great option, but unfortunately I don’t know how to develop it in Java and how to call this function in Java. Do you have any idea?

I’ll check ‘servr’, thaks

Comment: crudely, you poll, i.e. could run an infinite loop that sleeps (`Sys.sleep()`) for a specified amount of time between checks

Comment: Hey Ben, an infinite loop is my actual idea, but you'd agree with me that this is not a 'safe' option. hahaha

Comment: Based on @sinQueso's comment, you might use `servr:::watch_dir` ([current link](https://github.com/yihui/servr/blob/8fa9226fdf2004065e05368b3b65256797544652/R/static.R#L49)). *It is unexported*, so caveat emptor, but I think it does precisely what you're looking for. (You could easily just copy the function instead of using `servr:::watch_dir`.) (You'd need  to wrap it in a loop, I think, so perhaps not "precisely" what you want.)

Comment: if you use a UNIX/Linux system, there is also `inotifywait` that you can leverage: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/24952/script-to-monitor-folder-for-new-files

Comment: Thank you everyone, I have used a while(TRUE) and Keymetrics PM to run my R code.